# Display over other apps

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]I am facing issue while open image picker in android getting error is -> Display over the apps .
I am trying to enable it but my phone is not allowed to toggle .
I am using one plus 6 and android version is 9(Pie) .
can you please help me solve this error . 
Is there any code required to do for this .
here is an image to shows an error.

Comment: Your permission might be wrong. Make sure you're using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
`. WARNING: this permission will be deprecated in Android Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either misspelled the permission or haven’t added in the Manifest,

Add this - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`